Overleaf: 403 Forbidden Error - I lose access to my projects on the server!
A few months ago, I signed up in Overleaf and started a number of projects, I worked with Overleaf for a month. Now I try to log into my account again, but I can't access the domain at all
and I get the following error:

Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.

I don't know why this error happened to me. I guess it is because of restrictions against some countries!
I would be grateful if anyone who has encountered this problem can guide me so that I can just download my projects and continue on the my local system.
Because I don't have access to the overleaf domain in any way to contact them.

Did you try contacting overleaf, e.g. via https://www.overleaf.com/contact ?

As 403 signals an access problem, it's always worth checking yoour cookie setting for that page (and adjust it) ... Sometimes that's it.

@MS-SPO, I've tried several ways and finally I tried VPN tools and I can reach overleaf domain with a great difficulty then I downloaded all projects.
I'm not sure but I guess this restriction deliberately imposed by Overleaf against some countries. We have the experience of such an event from some companies.

Thank you for the response. Great, you could retrieve your projects. // Besides policy many other techical reasons can lead to what you observed.
